# How to call an external (gidas.rivile.lt) API from C#?

Tags: c#, api

I am trying to find a way regarding how to call [gidas.rivile.lt](https://gidas.rivile.lt/internetiniai_moduliai/api_rest/get_i44_list) `API` from `C#`. But not found a workaround yet. Have you ever worked on `gidas.rivile.lt` `API` calling mechanism?

I need to use the following `JSON` (`method` and `params`) in `C#` while calling `API`:

```
{
    "method": "GET_I44_LIST",
    "params": {
        "list": "A",
        "fil": "i44_modul='RO'"
    }
}
```

And what `BaseAddress` should I use? Please have a quick look into the specification as given here [gidas.rivile.lt](https://gidas.rivile.lt/internetiniai_moduliai/api_rest/get_i44_list). However, using `API-Key` and `Content-Type` seems to be not an issue.

Comment: One of the nice things about SOAP based webservices was that, by and large, they were easier to interact with; you knew the URL of the service and by tagging `?WSDL` on the end you either got a document describing the service, or you didn't. If you did, you could tell visual studio that you wanted to use the service at that url and it would query the WSDL and write a big bunch of code for you so that calling web service operations was just like any other method. That functionality is possible with REST services but it's less consistent. Hopefully rivile have published the equivalent spec..

Comment: ..but I couldn't find anything obvious browsing around the google translated version of the site. Have a look for mention of a Swagger or OpenAPI endpoint and if you find one, use the "Add REST Client" feature of VS or use NSwag or AutoRest to generate you some c# code to interact with the service; it really will take a huge amount of pain out of the process - otherwise you're down to putting something together to make an http request yourself, and possibly also provide some classes to ser/deser json to/from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have the following work around after some research:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.manorivile.lt/client/v2");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ApiKey", "ApiKey Value will be here");

    I44_SKOL_Collection i44_SKOL = new I44_SKOL_Collection();

    string paramObj = "{\"method\": \"GET_I44_LIST\",\"params\": {\"list\": \"A\",\"fil\": \"i44_modul='RO'\"}}";
    var content = new StringContent(paramObj, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, content);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
        };

        i44_SKOL = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<I44_SKOL_Collection>(jsonString, settings);

        if (i44_SKOL.I44 != null)
        {
            if (i44_SKOL.I44.Count > 0)
            {
                var i44_SKOL_Data = i44_SKOL.I44;
            }
        }            
    }
}
```